# How to save a function into a variable?

Tags: powershell

How to save a function into a variable?

```
function sayHello {
    write-host Hello, world!
}

$a = sayHello
```

Then, I want to call `$a`.

Another example:

```
$a = get-childItem
$a -name
```

Comment: Why would someone wants to do that ? and $a -name will throw error because $a will hold the contents of the get-childitem. not the the dot net library class to execute that from $a.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can refer to the function definition itself using the `function` variable scope qualifier:

```
$helloFunc = $function:sayHello
```

Now you can invoke it using the call operator (`&`):

```
& $helloFunc
```

The call operator supports parameters as well:

```
PS C:\> function test-param {param($a,$b) $b,$a |Write-Host}
PS C:\> $tp = ${function:test-param}
PS C:\> & $tp 123 456
456
123
PS C:\> & $tp -b 123 -a 456
123
456
```

Comment: Beautiful . I was not at all knowing this